# How to set Laravel 5 Middleware auth?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Larave 5 for my project. In my project i am using laravel default auth which use this command `php artisan make:auth`. And i set middleware in my route.php as shown

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::auth();    
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

    // Admin Roles Routes...
    Route::get('admin/roles', 'AdminController@showRoles');
});
```

Now my question is if i user is logout and click on browser back button user login and user can access like add, edit, delete view after logout. So how can i handle this situation. Please help i think some code i miss out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your Route::auth() does already has login and logout functions, if you run 'php artisan route:list' in your terminal you can see which routes are available etc..

Second of all you can create a group like shown below for your admin stuff:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::auth();    

    // Admin Roles Routes...
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'middleware'=>'auth'], function() {
        Route::get('roles', 'AdminController@showRoles');
    });
});
```

I hope this works for you ;)

Btw, the Laravel docs tell you a lot..., so make sure you watch them first ;)

Comment: but after log out user click on back button still all pages are working i want if user log out and user click on browser back button automatically redirect to login page

Comment: i have to write a code in other controller for auth?

Comment: I don't think you can change the 'back' button to redirect it to the login page.. that's why it is a back button.. The only thing you can do is make sure your routes, which must be protected, have an auth middleware so they can't change anything after they logout.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you don't need to apply `web` middleware as it already applied to your routes by `RouteServiceProvider`, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#registering-middleware

Secondly, when use `Route:auth()` it is a shortcut for:

```
$this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
$this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

$this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

$this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

So you don't need to define these routes:

```
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

Lastly, why you put login on your home page?

```
Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
```

This example should be work:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return 'Hello! You are logged in.';
    });

    // Admin Roles Routes...
    Route::get('admin/roles', 'AdminController@showRoles');
});

Route::auth();
```

With the routes above when unauthenticated user trying to access your home page `http://yoursite.com` and `http://yoursite.com/admin/roles`, user will be redirected to `http://yoursite.com/login` since those pages are protected by `auth` middleware.

Comment: this is requirement when site is load first page will be login

Comment: @dhanashri if so then you must apply `auth` middleware to your homepage route, if user not logged in he will be redirected to login page automatically.

Comment: i try lot's of time but i don't know what is my mistake.. or in my multiple controller put some code for auth

Comment: See edited answer, and try the example routes I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @Rick answer.

You can also manually set a middleware inside the __construct() function of your controller.

Example:

```
// SomeController.php

public function __construct()
{

    $this->middleware('auth');

}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#protecting-routes)